# Display all instances uptime

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm interested how I display all Oracle instances start time with one SQL Query?

```
select instance_name
       ,to_char(startup_time,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as startup_time 
from v$instance;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of RAC database there are gv$ views. Does this work for you?

```
select 
   instance_name,
   to_char(startup_time,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as startup_time ,
   systimestamp - startup as uptime
from gv$instance;
```

Comment: Yes, show me also for other editions for oracle, please.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Query works in almost all the versions. Is it not working for you?

Comment: Yes. In RAC, for every v$ view, you will have gv$ view which will give information for all instances.

Comment: How I can also display the uptime in days/minutes and etc?

Comment: select instance_name, systimestamp - startup_time from gv$instance;

Comment: @PeterPenzov, if your question is answered, please accept it as answer.